# Mass email to a list of contacts via Sparkpost

Tags: php, api, sparkpost

I would like to know if there is any existing implementation that sends mass email to a list of contacts using Sparkpost.

I am able to use API and PHP.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [php-sparkpost](https://github.com/SparkPost/php-sparkpost) library as Jim Wright mentioned. However, you can take either of the following approach with your list:

1) You can use the [Recipients List API](https://developers.sparkpost.com/api/recipient-lists.html) to upload all of your recipients to SparkPost. Then send an email ([transmission](https://developers.sparkpost.com/api/transmissions.html)) using that recipient list. See [this example](https://github.com/SparkPost/php-sparkpost/blob/master/examples/transmissions/create_transmission_with_recipient_list.php#L26) to learn how to use transmission along with recipient list. This way you can literally send an email to thousands of recipients in, like, just 2 API calls (one to create recipients list, one to transmission api)

2) You can use [inline recipients](https://github.com/SparkPost/php-sparkpost/blob/master/examples/transmissions/create_transmission.php#L26-L33) as shown in the example linked by Jim Write. However, there is a restriction in total payload size of transmission api (actually in `content` property of your json payload). So, you may have to split your transmissions into multiple API calls. And depending your total number of recipients/calls/frequency you may be subject to [API rate limiting](https://developers.sparkpost.com/api/index.html#header-rate-limiting).

Regardless of which method you follow, I will strongly advise you to follow [best practices suggested by SparkPost](https://www.sparkpost.com/email-deliverability-guide/), specially (along with others) increase your traffic gradually and build up your reputation before you shoot thousands of emails.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [php-sparkpost](https://github.com/SparkPost/php-sparkpost). I think that you should find the [first example](https://github.com/SparkPost/php-sparkpost#send-an-email-using-the-transmissions-endpoint) in the readme useful.

Also a related [blog post](https://www.sparkpost.com/blog/using-sparkpost-in-php/) by SparkPost.